# Send an email every week on the new subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, automation, filters

I would like to send an email every week to the new subscribers to my newsletter.

I want to use an automation and I am a bit lost between "data filter", "data filtered extension" and "filter".

What I have done so far :

In the step 1 of my automation, I have put an SQL query which update a data extension with all the newsletter subscribers.

What I want to do next :

In step 2, I want to filter on the newly subscribers AND to exclude those who might have already received the email.

To do so, I want to use a filter. But I want to be able to see somewhere (in a data extension) how many people will receive the email.

Can you help me, please ?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Laura, welcome to SFSE. I encourage you to check the [ask] article. Here, most of us prefer that you show what you've done and where you got stuck. In general, questions that ask people to "do it for me" don't get a lot of answers... though you never know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Add a new column in the data extension that will act as a flag. (eg IsNewCustomer). Set the default value to be equal to True.
2. In the body of your email, Use the [UpdateDE Ampscript function](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/updatede/) to update the value of this data extension to "False".
3. Create a filter interaction that picks off customers for which this column is true. This filter should be refreshed via an automation.
4. Send to these customers.